# How to translate 计算机及应用 into English?

Tags: translation

What's the proper English translation for the degree name "计算机及应用"?

Literally, 计算机=computer, 及=and, 应用=application. I think the name means computer and how to use computer in different scenarios. The courses of this major include subjects related with computer system architecture, computer algorithms and data structures, programming languages, software engineering, and many more.

Is one of these correct?

- Applied Computer
- Applied Computer Science
- Computer Application
- Computer and Application
- Computer Science

If none of above is correct, how should I translate it?

Comment: Although translation *into* English is on-topic, there are [requirements](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info) which help. Not everyone here reads Chinese, so as much information [in English] about what that text says needs to be included in the question. Without it, it risks being closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no definite answer.

For the name of bachelor degree, it is Applied Computer Science.
For the name of book, it is Computer Science and its Application.

Answer (score 4):

Computer (Theory) and Application.

This phrase seems odd because the word 原理 is missing. It should be 计算机原理及应用.

It can't be Computer and Application. In this context, 应用 does not mean computer programs but rather its use.

When 应用 is used in the context related to computer programs, it means the Apps on cellphones.

Comment: no problem. :) Nice answer regardless!

Comment: The computer theory is just one of the subjects, and it is not a major one. So if a student is specialized in "计算机及应用", it means the primary focus is how to use the practical technologies in computing.

Comment: @canoe If that,及 is verbose。 cut 及 or add 原理 is just two side of one thing

Answer (score 0):

"Computer Science" is correct.

Comment: Computer Science is 計算機科學

Answer (score 0):

"Computer Science and Application" might be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

It is "Calculator and Application". I'm from HK.

Comment: I am also from HK. Most of our computer science and computer engineering courses in our universities are translated to 计算机科學/工程. It has its historical root. Computation was translated to 電算 (電子計算). 
Computer, in academic context, usually would be translated to 計算機。